# Matlab Vectorising matrix subtraction using bsxfun

Tags: matlab, bsxfun

I have an array `Y=rand(1000,28);` I want to find the columnwise difference thus:

```
[~ c]=size(Y);

for i=1:c-1
Y(:,i)-Y(:,i+1)
end
```

Can I do this using `bsxfun`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do this using the function `diff`:

```
dY = -diff(Y, [], 2)
```

The `[]` and `2` tell `diff` to operate along the second dimension of Y, as specified in your question.

Note that this is actually faster, because `diff` is a built-in function:

```
>> Y = rand(100, 10000);
>> tic; for n = 1:1000; dY = -diff(Y, [] , 2); end; toc
Elapsed time is 5.453160 seconds.
>> tic; for n = 1:1000; dY = Y(:,1:end-1) - Y(:,2:end); end; toc
Elapsed time is 11.383666 seconds.
```

**Edit:** It has been suggested to use the `timeit` function to calculate these timings more accurately; the results are:

```
>> timeit(@()-diff(Y, [] , 2))

ans =

    0.0071

>> timeit(@()Y(:,1:end-1) - Y(:,2:end))

ans =

    0.0119
```

Also, putting these in an m-file appears not to make a difference in this case.

Comment: The `diff` function is nice for simple differences.  However, your timings are a bit questionable.  If the second form is put into an m-file, Matlab will likely compile it, and make the speed comparable.  You should also use the [`timeit`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18798) function for better accuracy here.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use bsxfun.  Do it the easy way:

```
dY = Y(:,1:end-1) - Y(:,2:end)
```